# NoClassDefFoundError with Spring maven hibernate org/hibernate/ejb/HibernatePersistence in my jUnit Test

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, junit

When I try and run my junit tests (which used to work, but magically stopped) I get

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/ejb/HibernatePersistence
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1030)
... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/ejb/HibernatePersistence
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.<init>(HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.java:57)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

My POM file does contain the org.hibernate dependency however:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>            
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

I've looked all over the internet but cannot find a solution.  Any thoughts on why this may be?

EDIT:  Fixed the Issue by running

> mvn clean install -U

Eclipse doesn't play nicely with Maven  :(

Answer (score 0):

Had to run

> mvn clean install -U
>
> mvn eclipse:clean
>
> mvn eclipse:eclipse

Then it worked